# Where and how to add SignalR in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, signalr

I'm creating a react app which implements SignalR and so far I have my connection and all the listeners in the component where I need them. The problem is that I have action creators in Redux which just make a request and get the response in order to call my server and send the data to all the other clients. Once the server emits the event to all clients, one of my listeners gets the data and calls an action creator which just dispatches an action to refresh my redux state.

I feel like I'm not using the action creators in the right way because I have one action creator which just makes the request and gets the response to return it and it's not changing the state.

If a had the socket connection in the store, I would just have to call one action creator and the logic to emit or listen to socket event, would be in other place.

This is my component,

```js
// --- component.js ---

state = {
    connection: null,
};

async componentDidMount() {
    // handles any network exception and show the error message
    try {
      await this.setupConnection();
    } catch (error) {
      this.showNetworkError(`Whoops, there was an error with your network connection. Please reload the page`);
}

setupConnection = () => {
    let { connection } = this.state;

    this.setState({
      connection: (connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(HUB_URL).build()),
    });

    /**
     * LISTENERS that are called from the server via websockets
     */
    connection.on('InsertTodo', data => {
      // action creator
      this.props.add(data);
    });

    connection.on('UpdateTodo', data => {
      // action creator
      this.props.update(data);
    });
}

createTodo = async todo => {

  const { connection} = this.state;

  // action creator
  const createdTodo = await this.props.createTodo(todo);
  if (createdTodo) {
    // the below sentence calls the server to emit/send the todo item to all other clients
    // and the listener in the setupConnection function is executed
    connection.invoke('EmitTodoCreate', createdTodo);
  } else {
    // there was a problem creating the todo
  }
};
```

This is the action creator

```js
// --- actionCreators.js ----
// ------------------------
export const add = todo => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_TODO,
      payload: todo,
    });
  };
};


export const createTodo = todo => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: START_REQUEST,
    });

    const response = await postTodo(todo);
    const result = await response.json();

    if (response.ok) {
      dispatch({
        type: SUCCESS_REQUEST,
      });
      // returns the todo item created in order to be sent to the server via websockets
      return result;
    }

    dispatch({
      type: FAILURE_REQUEST,
      error: result.error,
    });
    return null;
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is to implement a Redux middleware. It is easy, and you can use authentication for establishing connection, and you can dispatch action creators based on different messages emitted from SignalR.

Per the Redux FAQ, [the right place for websockets and other similar connections is in Redux middleware](https://redux.js.org/faq/codestructure#where-should-websockets-and-other-persistent-connections-live).

This is my custom middleware that establishes the connection, and registers the handlers. Please note that I only would like to receive data, and not interested in sending data. I use REST APIs to send data to server.

```
import {
  JsonHubProtocol,
  HttpTransportType,
  HubConnectionBuilder,
  LogLevel
} from '@aspnet/signalr'; // version 1.0.4

// action for user authentication and receiving the access_token
import { USER_SIGNED_IN } from '../actions/auth';

const onNotifReceived = res => {
  console.log('****** NOTIFICATION ******', res);
};

const startSignalRConnection = connection => connection.start()
  .then(() => console.info('SignalR Connected'))
  .catch(err => console.error('SignalR Connection Error: ', err));

const signalRMiddleware = ({ getState }) => next => async (action) => {
  // register signalR after the user logged in
  if (action.type === USER_SIGNED_IN) {
    const urlRoot = (window.appConfig || {}).URL_ROOT;
    const connectionHub = `${urlRoot}/api/service/hub`;

    const protocol = new JsonHubProtocol();

    // let transport to fall back to to LongPolling if it needs to
    const transport = HttpTransportType.WebSockets | HttpTransportType.LongPolling;

    const options = {
      transport,
      logMessageContent: true,
      logger: LogLevel.Trace,
      accessTokenFactory: () => action.user.access_token
    };

    // create the connection instance
    const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(connectionHub, options)
      .withHubProtocol(protocol)
      .build();

    // event handlers, you can use these to dispatch actions to update your Redux store
    connection.on('OperationProgress', onNotifReceived);
    connection.on('UploadProgress', onNotifReceived);
    connection.on('DownloadProgress', onNotifReceived);

    // re-establish the connection if connection dropped
    connection.onclose(() => setTimeout(startSignalRConnection(connection), 5000));

    startSignalRConnection(connection);
  }

  return next(action);
};

export default signalRMiddleware;
```

And inside my store.js file

```
import signalRMiddleware from '../middlewares/signalRMiddleware';

...

createStore(rootReducer, {}, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(signalRMiddleware)));
```

Comment: What to when there multiple `connectionHub` (more than one hub urls)?

Comment: @Akhilesh ,  I would say create multiple instances of "connection" with the other hub urls. The new "connection" instances will be able to handle new events on those hub urls.